# How to add more fields in the django admin panel's "add user" section?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

I am using Django 2.2 for building a private project.I am learning django advanced things like customizing admin panel, customizing user model and many more things. I have created my own user model with extra fields including Profile Picture, Mobile Number etc. In the admin-panel of django there is button named "Add User" and "add User" only contains UserName,Password and Password Confirmation Field.I want to add First Name, Last Name, Email, Mobile Number there.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/user/
```

Here there is a button named `"Add user"` and there is only Username,Password and confirm password.I want to add more fields there.
And I want to add another button named `"Create Admin"` which can create Admin
Is there any proper ways to do that?

Comment: Please show your existing code. Only after seeing what you have already coded, a person will be in better position to comment. Thank you